# Customized candy machine: ProgramError: 102: The program could not deserialize the given instruction

Tags: rust, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I've forked the [metaplex code](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex), and am trying to implement a candy machine with presale capabilities. You can see this pull request for reference: https://github.com/FluffyPorcupine/metaplex/pull/1/files. I've modified both the rust lib.rs and candy-machine-cli.ts files to implement how I think it might work.

I was able to successfully deploy the program to solana and anchor, deployed the idl to anchor (following [these steps](https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/tutorials/tutorial-0.html#building-and-emitting-an-idl)), and uploaded the files in the assets folder using the cli. My next step is to try and actually create a candy machine. This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-cli.ts create_candy_machine --env devnet --keypair .config/solana/devnet.json --presale-enabled true --presale-items-available 5
```

When I run the command, I get the following stack trace:

```
ProgramError: 102: The program could not deserialize the given instruction
    at Function.parse (/home/my-user/dev/Solana/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:41:14)   
    at Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/home/my-user/dev/Solana/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:23:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {  code: 102,
  msg: 'The program could not deserialize the given instruction'
}
```

I'm very new to debugging rust/anchor. Is there something in my code obvious to someone as to why I would be getting this error based on my changes in the PR to the relavant files? Or any tips on ways that I could debug this? I've tried running "anchor test" as well, but just get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about metaplex, but when I faced this same error a few times while using anchor and solana/web3, it was because of key mismatch key between `idl` file and the frontend rpc code.
For eg:
the idl file looked something like this

```
.....
"instructions": [
{
  "name": "initialize",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "baseAccount",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": true
    },
    {
      "name": "authority",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": true
    },
    {
      "name": "systemProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    }
  ],
  "args": []
},
{
..... and so on
```

And in the frontend, where I tried to access the program

```
  const provider = await getProvider(wallet);

  const { SystemProgram, Keypair } = web3;
  /* create an account  */
  const baseAccount = Keypair.generate();

  const programID = new PublicKey(
    ".... The Public key here ....."
  );

const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
    
      try {
        /* interact with the program via rpc */
        await program.rpc.initialize({
          accounts: {
            mainAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
            authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
          },
          signers: [baseAccount],
        });
    ....and so on
```

I used `mainAccount` in frontend rpc instead of `baseAccount`, which was the key in the idl file. It had to be

```
await program.rpc.initialize({
          accounts: {
            baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
            authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
          },
          signers: [baseAccount],
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to have different type of parameters with your handler vs the instruction macro you will get this error. ie. you used `u8` in the handler param then you have `usize` inside `#[instruction()]` macro:

```rust
pub fn some_ix(ctx: Context<SomeIx>, index: u8) -> Result<()> {
  // ...
}

// then

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(index: usize)] // <- this is what causing the issue
pub struct SomeIx {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the variables that contains the values that needs to be passed on the RPC call.

I got the same error when I have mistakenly initialised the variable as

```
myVariable : "Hello";
```

Instead of,

```
myVariable = "Hello";
```